# Large dataset - choosing specific rows after having chosen columns

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics

I'm using quite a large dataset with many, or even multiple rows having similar names to them.

[image: Data]

This is the code I've been using so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dataset_20001_20180801113759.csv")
df = df.set_index(["Small Molecule HMS LINCS ID"])

Chosen_SmallMoleculeName="10104-101-1"
df2 = df.loc[Chosen_SmallMoleculeName, ["Cell count", "% Apoptotic cells"]]
df3 = df2.loc[Chosen_SmallMoleculeName, "Cell count"]

df4 = df.loc[Chosen_SmallMoleculeName, "Cell count"]
print("Cell count")
print(df4.values)

df5 = df.loc[Chosen_SmallMoleculeName, "% Apoptotic cells"]
print("% Apoptotic cells")
print(df5.values)
```

With this, it is printing out the entire columns of "Cell count", and "% Apoptotic cells", which is too large to copy and paste here. From the image above, I want to try and just obtain rows 2-7 specific data.

The dataset can be obtained from here: http://lincs.hms.harvard.edu/db/datasets/20001/results

**Question 1:** How can I choose rows 2 to 7 specific data of "Cell count" and "% Apoptotic cells"?

**Question 2 (Not as important, but I am wondering)**:Is it possible to do this "dynamically"? As in, instead of myself manually having to look at each row to find the unique or related ones, is it possible to write the code that chooses rows 2-7 to be printed, but intuitively chooses, say rows 14 to 19? I feel this would be delving into machine learning territory...

I have looked at the Python API and have not found a similar question.

Comment: Is your `df2` not already exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: What is the property that you are looking for in rows 2-7 and 14-19? If you were to explain more clearly what you are looking for it might be solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve rows from `2` to `7` you can use [slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), once you have considered that you have to subtract 1 for the header and another 1 since arrays start from 0:

```
result = df[:6][["Cell count", "% Apoptotic cells"]]
```

With the result being:

```
          Cell count       % Apoptotic cells
0         576              60.59
1         373              79.09
2         436              56.19
3         654              43.88
4         284              58.10
5         574              41.81
```

*Now, if you were to explain more thoroughly what is the property you are interested in extracting from this dataset we could help you out with that too.*